# GoogleCloudMessaging linked error

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-cloud-messaging

I need to use **GoogleCloudMessaging** in my app. I installed it via **Cocoapods**. 
When I added this part of code:

```
GLInstanceIDConfig *instanceIDConfig = [GGLInstanceIDConfig defaultConfig];
    instanceIDConfig.delegate = self;
    // Start the GGLInstanceID shared instance with the that config and request a registration
    // token to enable reception of notifications
    [[GGLInstanceID sharedInstance] startWithConfig:instanceIDConfig];
    _registrationOptions = @{kGGLInstanceIDRegisterAPNSOption:deviceToken,
                             kGGLInstanceIDAPNSServerTypeSandboxOption:@YES};
    [[GGLInstanceID sharedInstance] tokenWithAuthorizedEntity:GCMSSenderID
                                                        scope:kGGLInstanceIDScopeGCM
                                                      options:_registrationOptions
                                                      handler:_registrationHandler];
```

And I have these errors:

> Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
>   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GGLInstanceID", referenced from:
>         objc-class-ref in AppDelegate.o   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GGLInstanceIDConfig", referenced from:
>         objc-class-ref in AppDelegate.o   "_kGGLInstanceIDAPNSServerTypeSandboxOption", referenced from:
>         -[AppDelegate application:didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:] in
>   AppDelegate.o   "_kGGLInstanceIDRegisterAPNSOption", referenced from:
>         -[AppDelegate application:didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:] in
>   AppDelegate.o   "_kGGLInstanceIDScopeGCM", referenced from:
>         -[AppDelegate application:didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:] in
>   AppDelegate.o ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64 clang:
>   error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see
>   invocation)

Project settings:

-> Build Active Architecture Only  - YES

-> Other Linked Flags contains $(inherited)

-> Deployment target - 8.0

Please help me!
Thanks in advance!

Comment: make sure you are building the workspace, not the project, because CocoaPods is another separate project in the workspace

Answer (score 1):

Check for 4 things:

1. You have not manually uploaded **GoogleCloudMessaging** in your project. If there is any, delete them and reinstall pods.
2. Check your **linker Path settings in build settings**. Use '**$inherited**' before installing pod.
3. After reinstalling pods, clean your project with <kbd>cmd</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>k</kbd> and then run your project.
4. Build Active Architecture Only - NO, and for Targets -YES

Answer (score 0):

This error is because of some missing libraries in your project.

Check in your `Build Phases -> Link Binary With Libraries`. Any of your framework may had been removed from there.

Add it and Clean and Build your project.

May be it will help you.